# Install PHP GMP on Manjaro

Tags: php, manjaro

I recently moved from Kubuntu to Manjaro. On Manjaro (an Arch-based distro), there doesn't seem to be a package for GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) support for PHP. I only need it to work on the command line (PHP shell via `php -a`). How can I install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there is no package to add GMP support to PHP under Manjaro because it's not really needed. I had to install the GMP library via

```
sudo pacman -S gmp
```

and then enable GMP support in PHP's settings. For the latter, I searched for all PHP ini files on my computer:

```
find / -name "*php*.ini" 2> /dev/null
```

This only printed:

```
/etc/php/php.ini
```

In this file, there is this line:

```
;extension=gmp
```

After removing the semicolon, it worked.

Comment: Instead, use the command: `php --ini` Example of output :
`Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php/php.ini Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/conf.d Additional .ini files parsed: (none)`

Comment: @LydaLauras Cool, thank you. That's nice to know.